# How to exclude local traffic from AWStats reports?

Tags: localhost, awstats, filter

I have AWStats configured to run on my website, but I would like it to exclude hits coming from myself (localhost) that are seen as originating from these ip addresses:

```
127.0.0.1
192.168.0.1
```

How can I configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to edit your .conf file, and change the SkipHosts parameter.

For your needs, this would be:

```
SkipHosts = "127.0.0.1 192.168.0.1"
```

If your IP address changes on your private network, or if you start accessing your site from multiple computers, you would probably want to match your IP addresses via Regular Expressions.

```
SkipHosts = "127.0.0.1 REGEX[^192\.168\.]"
```

For reference, the FAQ is provided [here](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_faq.html#EXCLUDEHOSTS)

Note that sometimes localhost hits can also come up as originating from the **::1** ip address, so you may need to add that too.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [this](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_faq.html#EXCLUDEHOSTS) section of the awstats faq, this is the solution to your problem. there are also some examples.